# Pass attribute in spring from controller to external url and back

Tags: java, spring

I have some external url for payment. After payment is done it redirects to me back.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/first", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String first(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
  doSomething(id);
  return "redirect:/externalurl"
}

// This method is called from external url
@RequestMapping(value = "/second", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String second() {
  // I want to get here id from first call 
}
```

Is it possible somehow to do it with `RedirectAttributes` or other similar approach like to add it in `first()` method and to get it in `second()` method ?

Comment: Usually you tell your payment provider which of your endpoints it should use for callbacks...

Comment: Ok yes, but is there any workaround without involving payment provider?

Comment: I thought that was the whole point of the question...